# Django Calculation inside HTML

Tags: django, django-views

I wanted to do something simmilar to this suing django. but somehow i it doesn't work. how do i fix it?

```
for statik in statistik{
print(statik*total/100)
}
```

Is there any documentation regarding what I'm trying to implement to my django app? Thank you
Here's the HTML :

```
                  {% if statistics  %}
                    {% for statik in statistics|slice:":4"  %}
                    <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">{{ statik.name }}
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>{{ statik.voters }} of {{ total }} Voters</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ statik.voters * total/100 }}%" aria-valuenow="50"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %} <p>END TABLE</p>
                {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended you do calculations of any sort in view and pass it in context.

If you still want to go this route there are no math template tags except [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) included so you should create [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) or use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/)

Comment: how do i do the calculation in views?
for I in data : ??